# How to parse "Нам есть, чему поучиться"

Tags: грамматика

> Нам есть, чему поучиться.

I assume the entire phrase means something along the lines of "we could learn a thing or two from them/that", but I'm not sure how to parse this construction, interpreting it more literally.

Comment: in this case comma is redundant

Comment: [For] us [there] is, what [to] learn.

Comment: There's a thing or two we could learn

Comment: This is a set-phrase, not only grammar is important here @Alex_ander gave the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it can be parsed as follows

> There's (that) which is for us to learn

In Russian it's an impersonal construction.

The reverse construction would be

> У нас есть чему поучиться - We have (that) which is to be learned

**что** is inflected in Dative as **чему** because this is the case in which the verb **учиться** accepts object denoting the item of learning.

Basically `object in Dative + есть + relative pronoun + infinitive` is a stable construction.

> Нам **есть куда** пойти - We have places to go (there's no shortage) <sup>*more lit. There're places for us to go*</sup>
>
> <sup>negative</sup> *Нам **некуда**...  - We have no...*
>
> Им **есть что** смотреть - They have something/things to watch (there's no shortage)
>
> <sup>negative</sup> *Им **нечего** ... - They have nothing ...*
>
> Мне **есть зачем** жить - I have reasons to live/what to live for
>
> <sup>negative</sup> *Мне **незачем** ... - I have no reasons to live/nothing to live for*

Comment: No commas. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC

Answer (score 2):

> Нам есть чему поучиться.

It's an impersonal sentence which is formed with the verb "to be"(есть ), an object in the form of a pronoun in the dative case(чему), another verb in the infinitive form (поучиться)functioning as an attribute to the object, and the agent of the action expressed by the infinitive also in the dative, which is traditional in impersonal sentences. It corresponds to English

> There's something to learn for us.

There are a lot of sentences of this kind and there's **never a comma** in them.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is *typically* about learning from **somebody**'s *unique or superior skills or knowledge*, **not** about getting *any missing knowledge* (that *somebody* is often *known* from context and can be omitted):

> Нам есть чему (у него, у них) поучиться.

So I'll try to literally parse it this way:

> There is something for us (what) to learn (from them) for some time.

Word by word, parsing it backwards:

**There is (something)** - есть (то)

**for us** - Нам

**(what) to learn** - чему учиться

**to learn for some time** - **по**учиться

**Поучиться** as opposed to **учиться** means that there's a limited opportunity (*'while possible'*) to learn from somebody who's definitely not hired for teaching.